# Problem in uploading image in Asp core web api and angular8

Tags: asp.net-core

I am having trouble while uploading images with `asp core api` and `angular8`.

Uploading works with `PostMan`. 
But when uploading from `angular`, it is not working 
and appear this problem:

> Incorrect Content-Type: application/json

I send `Content-Type` in `httpInterceptor`

Code in photos description here [image: code implementation]

Comment: Please replace the image with codes. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: when you post formdata along with file upload, it should be `content-type:multipart/form-data`